# Mysqlserver can't start in lamp debian 8

Tags: mysql

I installed LaMp 2 days ago. First everything works;
But until yesterday, I can't start anymore mysql server : it failed each time.
When I look at the status :

```
systemctl status mysql
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Erreur inconnue -1
```

It's like it can't generate mysqld.sock

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

I keep reading man and trying to find something I didn't configure correctly, but I can't find nothing. 
Please, help me to resolve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this command in a terminal:

```
sudo service dbus restart
```

or this:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dbus restart
```

Probably this is a temporary solution, this means that you'll have to do that command everytime you got the dbus error.